# What's the Difference between the two of writings of arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, generics, typescript

> TypeScript, like JavaScript, allows you to work with arrays of values.
>   Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use
>   the type of the elements followed by '[]' to denote an array of that
>   element type:

```
var list:number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

> The second way uses a generic array type, Array:

```
var list:Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

**Are there any difference between these two syntax? Is there a good reason for 2 ways to write these?** (I know generics are a thing in other languages but I've never used generics in any past lang).

[Documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-array)

Comment: I would imagine it's to align with Javascript in a strongly-typed way. I mean, in Javascript you can also do `[]` and `new Array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent. The `number[]` form is shorthand for the `Array<number>` generic.

The "array type literal" from [section 3.7.4 of the spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) is defined as:

> An array type literal references an array type (section 3.3.2) with the given element type.

The "array type" from [section 3.3.2](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) are described as:

> Array types are named type references created from the generic interface type 'Array' in the global module with the array element type as a type argument.

This notes that arrays are defined as a generic type with an argument. The generic is the definitive version, but that description is followed immediately by:

> Array type literals (section 3.7.4) provide a shorthand notation for creating such references.

There is no difference, the `type[]` form exists as a shorthand using pre-existing JS patterns.